# xpath expression to find all occerence of a element in html file

Tags: java, html, xpath

I have an html file where I need to find the number of occurrences of the `<object>` tag. In Java I'm using the XPathExpression `//:object[contains(@type,"video/") or contains(@type,"audio/")]` to find the occurences of the `<object>` tag. It's detecting the `<object>` tag but I want the count of number of object tags present in my file.

```
result = (Boolean) expression.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
```

where inputSource contains my html file. It is returning a boolean value, when I tried the same thing with
`xpathValue = (Double) expression.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NUMBER);` getting result as NaN.

What's the solution?

Comment: BTW the expression you showed is not valid XPath. You can't have a colon in an element name test without a namespace prefix before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit fuzzy on my Java and Xpath, but if you evaluate

`expression.evaluate(inputSource, XPathConstants.NODELIST)`

You should get back a NodeList of all the Nodes matching your query, and you can just get the length of that list.

Comment: Alternatively, wrap your expression in a call to the XPath "count(...)" function, and evaluate the result as a double.

Comment: @Michael Good point, I rarely use Java XPath so I'm glad you could bring that function up, I had no idea it existed.