# XPath expression to find vides

Tags: video, xpath, expression

I am trying to access videos with XPath on URL... I have tested it with next basic expressions:

- //div
- //a
- //.....

And now I would like to receive data about video and I tried this:

- //:object[contains(@type,"video/") (also found on stackoverflow - [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778854/xpath-expression-to-find-all-occerence-of-a-element-in-html-file))

And I don't receive any data on youtube... How can I do that?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Show us a sample of the input XML; without this, it's impossible to know what XPath expression is needed. Don't expect your readers to look up youtube XML format, if you can easily provide it.

Comment: Or are you trying to screenscrape the HTML from youtube? What data, specifically, are you trying to access? HTML object elements? Show a sample of the data you want to select from.

Comment: HTML from YouTube... and I am trying to access HTML object elements..

Comment: Voted to close. OP unwilling to post a sample.

Answer (score 1):

> And now I would like to receive data about video and I tried this:
>
> ```
> //:object[contains(@type,"video/")
> ```
>
> (also found on stackoverflow - LINK)  And I don't receive any data on
>   youtube... How can I do that?

**This**:

```
//:someName
```

**is invalid in XPath (both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0)**

**You can either have**:

```
//someName
```

**or**

```
//*[local-name() = 'someName']
```

**or in XPath 2.0**:

```
//*:someName
```

Comment: The XPath expression in this question is also only half of the one in the example found elsewhere, and it's missing the final `]`.

Comment: @LarsH: Good to know. I haven't had time to look at the original example.

Comment: So what would be full example for XPath expression to find video

Comment: @M.V.: This depends on the XML document, which you haven't shown to us.

Comment: @M.V.: I guess what you need is: `//div[@class='video-title']` or maybe `//div[@class='video-title']//a/@href`

Comment: The problem is that I am looking for overall tool... not just youtube... I would like to mark videos on any web page visited...

Comment: I am not sure you can recognize the URLs for videos on any web page -- in general this isn't possible.